# Dask memory usage exploding even for simple computations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dask, parquet

I have a `parquet` folder created with `dask` containing multiple files of about 100MB each. When I load the dataframe with `df = dask.dataframe.read_parquet(path_to_parquet_folder)`, and run any sort of computation (such as `df.describe().compute()`), my kernel crashes.

Things I have noticed:

- CPU usage (about 100%) indicates that multithreading is not used
- memory usage shoots way past the size of a single file
- the kernel crashes after system memory usage approaches 100%

### EDIT:

I tried to create a reproducible example, without success, but I discovered some other oddities, seemingly all related to the newer `pandas` dtypes that I'm using:

```py
import pandas as pd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
ProgressBar().register()
from dask.diagnostics import ResourceProfiler
rprof = ResourceProfiler(dt=0.5)
import dask.dataframe as dd

# generate dataframe with 3 different nullable dtypes and n rows
n = 10000000
test = pd.DataFrame({
    1:pd.Series(['a', pd.NA]*n, dtype = pd.StringDtype()), 
    2:pd.Series([1, pd.NA]*n, dtype = pd.Int64Dtype()),
    3:pd.Series([0.56, pd.NA]*n, dtype = pd.Float64Dtype())
})

dd_df = dd.from_pandas(test, npartitions = 2) # convert to dask df

dd_df.to_parquet('test.parquet') # save as parquet directory

dd_df = dd.read_parquet('test.parquet') # load files back

dd_df.mean().compute() # compute something
dd_df.describe().compute() # compute something
dd_df.count().compute() # compute something
dd_df.max().compute() # compute something
```

Output, respectively:

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['2', '1', '3'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['2', '1', '3'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

`Kernel appears to have died.`

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['2', '1', '3'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

It seems that the dtypes are preserved even throughout the parquet IO, but dask has some trouble actually doing anything with these columns.

Python version: `3.9.7`
dask version: `2021.11.2`

Comment: Do you instantiate the cluster manually? Also, Parquet file size can be misleading due to compression.

Comment: What do you mean by "instantiate the cluster"? I am running dask locally. The Parquet folder contains a metadata file. I can use `df.get_partition(0).compute()` without problems, the memory usage of a single partition is about 500MB.

Comment: Thanks for the question! Diagnosing performance issues or cluster setup problems in dask is epsecially tricky. This problem would be more likely to get a high quality response with a [mre], especially one that gives significantly more detail about the dask setup, how you're provisioning your cluster (just `client = dd.Client()`?), and a minimal set of code and data (or ideally data generated with code) required to reproduce the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado! Reproducing Kernel crashes reliably can also be tricky, but I understand that it is required for a proper understanding of a bug/problem. I will try to come up with something.

Comment: I totally sympathize! But that's not typical dask.dataframe behavior - I use it all the time without this issue. So unless we see your code and setup it's hard for us to know what's going on, especially given the complexity of the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this happen for all methods, or just `describe`? I ask, because that includes std.dev and percentiles, which are not trivial to calculate. What is the total size of the dataset, how many files?

Comment: It's a minor thing, but naming the columns using strings rather than ints, will remove the `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the main error is due to `NAType` which is not yet fully supported by `numpy` (version `1.21.4`):

```
~/some_env/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _var(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims, where)
    240     # numbers and complex types with non-native byteorder
    241     else:
--> 242         x = um.multiply(x, um.conjugate(x), out=x).real
    243 
    244     ret = umr_sum(x, axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims, where=where)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type NAType which has no callable conjugate method
```

As a workaround, casting columns to float will compute the descriptives. Note that to avoid `KeyError` the column names are given as strings rather than `int`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

ProgressBar().register()
from dask.diagnostics import ResourceProfiler

rprof = ResourceProfiler(dt=0.5)
import dask.dataframe as dd

# generate dataframe with 3 different nullable dtypes and n rows
n = 1000

# note that column names are changed to strings rather than ints
test = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "1": pd.Series(["a", pd.NA] * n, dtype=pd.StringDtype()),
        "2": pd.Series([1, pd.NA] * n, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype()),
        "3": pd.Series([0.56, pd.NA] * n, dtype=pd.Float64Dtype()),
    }
)

dd_df = dd.from_pandas(test, npartitions=2)  # convert to dask df

dd_df.to_parquet("test.parquet", engine="fastparquet")  # save as parquet directory

dd_df = dd.read_parquet("test.parquet", engine="fastparquet")  # load files back

dd_df.mean().compute()  # compute something
dd_df.astype({"2": "float"}).describe().compute()  # compute something
dd_df.count().compute()  # compute something
dd_df.max().compute()  # compute something
```

Comment: Thanks @Sultan for providing the workaround! I've also opened up an [issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8530) for this.